# Dropout Decreases Test and Train Accuracy in one layer LSTM in Pytorch

Tags: lstm, pytorch, dropout

I have a one layer lstm with pytorch on Mnist data. I know that for one layer lstm dropout option for lstm in pytorch does not operate. So, I have added a drop out at the beginning of second layer which is a fully connected layer. However, I observed that without dropout I get 97.75% accuracy on the test data and with dropout of 0.5 I get 95.36%. I want to ask whether I am doing something wrong or what is the reason for this phenomena? 
I change it into eval mode in test but I reach to 96.44% accuracy. Still it is less than without dropout.
Thanks a lot

```python
# RNN Model (Many-to-One)
class RNN(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers,
                        batch_first=True,bidirectional=True)

    self.fc = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(0.1),
       nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, num_classes),
        nn.Softmax(dim=1)
    )
def init_hidden(self,x):

     return(Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)).cuda(), 
     Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).cuda()))

def forward(self, x):
    # Set initial states 


    # Forward propagate RNN

    hidden = self.init_hidden(x)
    #print(len(hidden))
    out, _ = self.lstm(x, hidden)  

    # Decode hidden state of last time step
    out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])  
    return out
```

Comment: Did you change your model from training to evaluation mode when running your test data?
http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.train

Comment: Thanks yes. I did

Comment: I think you should use dropout after linear layer.